# BeautifulSoup - Multiple tables

Tags: beautifulsoup

I´m in doubt how to extract multiple tables from one html page. We have 2 types of tables and I want to import to a dataframe only the tables with the same style (table with a lot of columns)

[image]

```
from  urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://61b474eb50d60.htmlsave.net/"

response = urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

soup.table return only the first table.. but i want the tables with columnns INFO1, INFO2.. until Status

Also I would like to import to a dataframe

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the HTML snippet? or even the website that you want to scrape? I'd also suggest to write what you tried already

Comment: In addition to @ezzeddin - Also check your url it will give you a *404*

Comment: I tried soup.table .. but this only return the first table

Comment: I have problem with the htmlsave.net... then i will share the html here: 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19oOhBmSMiAIAMJt1v1lwUhRh6z52Ac1M

Answer (score 0):

Just let pandas parse the tables. You will need to add a little logic though as the headers are on their own `<table>` tags. It looks like both tables you are after are identical though:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://61b474eb50d60.htmlsave.net/"
dfs = pd.read_html(url)

tables = []
for idx, table in enumerate(dfs):
    if len(table.columns > 1) and len(table) > 1:
        temp_df = table.dropna(how='all', axis=0)
        temp_df.columns = dfs[idx-1].iloc[0]
        
        tables.append(temp_df)
```

**Output:**

```
for table in tables:
    print(table, '\n')

0     INFO1     INFO2       INFO3     INFO4  Number Reg INFO6 INFO7      Status
0   NUMBER1  J0B57959  10/12/2021  04:39:11         184   TST   TST  ERROR COD8
1  NUMBER20  J0B57950  10/12/2021  04:39:05         277   TST   TST  ERROR COD8
2   NUMBER3  30B57951  10/12/2021  04:39:04         277   TST   TST  ERROR COD8 

0     INFO1     INFO2       INFO3     INFO4  Number Reg INFO6 INFO7      Status
0   NUMBER1  J0B57959  10/12/2021  04:39:11       184.0   TST   TST  ERROR COD8
1  NUMBER20  J0B57950  10/12/2021  04:39:05       277.0   TST   TST  ERROR COD8
2   NUMBER3  30B57951  10/12/2021  04:39:04       277.0   TST   TST  ERROR COD8
```